# Is there a way to extract a row name with R?

Tags: r, list, function, dataframe, extract

I'm new to R, I have started using it few months ago. I'm using it for my thesis and I'm stucked in extracting the name of a row and then use it within another function. To better explain what I mean, here is the code:

I have three dataframe: 
- requestinfo ( containing all the characteristics of a construction site' battery storage demand, for 300 demand in total) 
- constructionsites ( containing the longitude and the latitude of every construction site,the index of the 1st closest hub to the construction site,the index of the the 2nd closest hub, the index of the the 3rd closest hub and the index of the 4th closest hub) 
- storing hub ( containing the longitude, the latitude  of every storage hub and the number of battery placed in the hub which ranges from 0 battery (empty hub) to 6 batteries (full hub)) this dataframe has been created by adding together several vectors containing 2 elements, respectively longitude and latitude and they were named with the hub name.

I have created a function that for a given construction site name ( which is taken by another function from the request info dataframe) it should return the name of either the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th closest hub. 
This is the function for returning the 1st closest hub

```
name_closest <- function(con_name){
yo <- as.character(con_name)
nearest_hubs <-  constructionsites[yo,"nearest_hubs"]
hub<-hubs[nearest_hubs,0]
return(hub)
}
```

**The problem is that I am not able to get "hub" as a character ( using typeof() both hubs and hub are a list) , so for example:**

```
yo <- as.character("woningen_32_poststraat")
nearest_hubs <-  constructionsites[yo,"nearest_hubs"]
x<-hubs[nearest_hubs,0]
```

0 is the column with the hubs name

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0i0iR.jpg)

The problem is that later on in the code **I would like to use the variable x ( in the example the name "shipdock_amsterdam") for another function that access to the hub dataframe, find the hub with the x name and then the function either reduces or increases by a number n the no. of battery stored in the given hub.**

This is the function to decrease/increase the number of battery

```
hubs[x,4]-n
```

I get the following error

```
**hubs[x,]
Error in xj[i] : invalid subscript type 'list'**
```

That's because I am not able to extrapolate the character, Indeed if I manually do

```
hubs["shipdock_amsterdam",4]-n
```

the code functions perfectly and it subtracts the number of available batteries.

**So, how could I get the character rather than the string from the column 0? I tried also to convert it using unlist() and as.character() but I always get NULL.**

Excuse me for the extensive description, and thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the value of `x` May be you need `hubs[names(x),]$container10ft[2]-n` or `hubs[colnames(x),]$container10ft[2]-n` or if it is rownames, change it to `row.names(x)`

Comment: The way to get an answer is to post a [MCVE] and has how to do X with the values in the example. Mayke 3 small objects of similar structure to the ones you are working with. We cannot possibly do troubleshooting with the vague descriptions offered.

Comment: The value of x is shown in the picture. It is a list containing a name of an hub, in this case shipdock_amsterdam, the problem is that I am not able to convert it  from a list variable into a character variable, therefore R gives me an error saying that it cannot use x as an index in the hubs dataframe